# Xcode 11: Self signed root for signer

Tags: ios, code-signing, xcode11

> Warning: unable to build chain to self-signed root for signer "iPhone Distribution:"
>   Appname.app: errSecInternalComponent
>   Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code

[image]

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Probably a duplicate among those: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+%22root+for+signer%22

Comment: @Cœur That was my point, eh...

Comment: anyone find the answer to this question. I suddenly started getting it as well